# Changing playback speed using gstreamer

Tags: c, gstreamer, playback

I am currently working on the [gstreamer tutorials](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/index.html), in particular the [one](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/playback-speed.html?gi-language=c) about playback speed adjustments. I pasted the example code into a file which I compiled with the flags `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0` (my `gstreamer` version is `1.20.5`)

I tried to change the playback rates using the keys `S` / `s`, got the corresponding prints (`Current rate: 0.5` etc.) but the playback speed stayed constant at 1. I thought that the failure to change the playback speed was due to the source being a remote file, so I changed the code to use local files (as command line arguments) instead:

```
gchar buffer[4096];

g_snprintf(buffer, 4096, "playbin uri=file://%s", argv[1]);

/* Build the pipeline */
data.pipeline = gst_parse_launch(buffer, &error);
```

I also switched from the video sink to an audio sink (audio is sufficient for my cases).

I then noticed that whether or not the rate changed works is (apparently) up to the type of the file I am opening: When I open a local `ogg` file, the playback speed changes, when I open an `mp3` instead, nothing happens.

Is this a bug in `gstreamer`, or do I need a more sophisticated pipeline in order to get the approach to work with different media types (local files would be sufficient for my needs)?

Edit: [Complete code](https://gist.github.com/ax487/319f9b5ba793b6c7e6d65e1f39e33b1c), [sample mp3](https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-15s.mp3)

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. Confusingly, the example file did not work over HTTP, but did work when saved locally through a `file://` URI!

As a workaround, for audio, there is the [pitch element](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/soundtouch/pitch.html).